# Suspending UWP apps using back button

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is there a way i can "suspend" a UWP app by pressing the back button.
I'm not even sure suspending is the right term but what i want to do is to close the app when the user presses the back button rather than going back to the Signup/Login page in my app.
I want the app go close but also still be shown when the user opens the recent apps menu by holding the back button.
Heres my code in the App.Xaml.Cs

```
 private void OnBackRequested(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.BackRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if (rootFrame.CurrentSourcePageType == typeof(Pages.Home))
            {
                App.Current.Exit();
            }
            if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                rootFrame.GoBack();
            }
        }
```

The Problem is with the App.Current.Exit(); 
it terminates the app where what i want to do is just close and and not go back to the MainPage.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To leave your app without terminating it, just remove the `App.Current.Exit();` and ignore the back event (`e.Handled = false;`). You will then get the default behavior which is to leave the app on mobile devices. On desktop, your app will stay on the page it is. You will then have to do anything that fit your need to save/restore your app in its appropriate state using the suspending/resuming event handlers.

```
void OnBackRequested(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (rootFrame.CurrentSourcePageType == typeof(Pages.Home))
        {
            // ignore the event. We want the default system behavior
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            rootFrame.GoBack();
        }
}
```

Comment: This brings me back to the Login/Signup page, where i want the app to do is act like there are no pages left and terminate itself when I'm on the homepage

Comment: I forgot the "else" clause; I've updated my answer. With your code, the rootFrame.CanGoBack was always evaluated and was always returning 'true' since you have a page in the history so a back navigation was always performed. You can also remove the Login/Signup page from the history by clearing the rootFrame.BackStack.